# Module pdo_mysql ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available

Tags: pdo

I recently upgraded to PHP7, now I learned to find out out while connecting to Laravel, with this problem [PDOException] could not find driver.How am I going to configure or install it?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Following steps are working for me

Installing php7.0-mysql

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

You will then need to ensure the module is enabled:

```
sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql
```

Then restart Apache to load the new modules:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```